# TypeScript: infer record union value

Tags: typescript

```
interface Num {
    type: 'number',
    default: number
}

interface Bool {
    type: 'boolean'
    default: boolean
}

interface Str {
    type: 'string',
    default: string
}

type UnionType = Num | Bool | Str

interface IOption<T extends string, CFG extends Record<T, UnionType>> {
    configs: CFG,
    // I don't know how to write this line to make each key matches its own value type
    // i.e. `{key1: Num, key2: Bool, key3: Str}`
    defaultOverwrite?: Partial<{ [key in T]: CFG[key]['default'] }>
}

declare function checker<T extends string, CFG extends Record<T, UnionType>>(option: IOption<T, CFG>): void

checker({
    configs: {
        // key1 errors as expected, which default should be a number
        key1: { type: 'number', default: '' },
        key2: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        key3: { type: 'string', default: 'string' },
    },
    defaultOverwrite: {
        // the value of `key1` should match the type of configs.key1.default, which is a number.
        // expected error here, but I don't know how
        key1: '3'
    }
})
```

See the above case.

I want to check the `configs` type which value should matches `UnionType`,
also, I want to check `defaultOverwrite` type, which should has partial key of `configs` and the corresponding value type as the `configs` declared.

But I don't know how, anyone can help me?

I rethought about my question, the real problem is we need to make a union value record to become exact type when assigned value, like

```
type A = {[key: string]: string | number}
// when declared
const a: A = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 'str'
}
```

I want `a` to match type `A` but also generate a exact type which is

```
interface ExactA{
  key1: number,
  key2: string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2yDeAoZQ5MATwAcIAuZAchCwCNoaAaAogEwnnQBsxq9TEyh4AvnjyhIsRCgBCAe0W9c7QqQrUaDZbwhwQNdci49+1XSoMhxk6dHhJkAZTBQ1RYuSq0Azu6gAOasJmZwfALIAVDBdniaKACqIMCKIAAqPsgAvGhYyAA+yEoqRa7u9uCOcsgAkgDyZGBpIAA8GcgQAB6QIBx+0YEgQSzIAMIAYgDiXb0Q-YMAShAIilAcHWMprVkUAHz7nkRrIDDAQX7UU9NsXgD09-Wm6TRgyADWIIoA7sgAFr9iIpkD9YpBiP9gINeKAUGAQZg4B8UAYEP9PhASMgkWB0RBBsAwINfiBkAA3OC8dDwnwmR7IYAAOggTOQAAMcCiSABGagYTBjbkAJmopV4QqxAGZqG4oGJ2WFuBF+A1ydAwUSIAB+agABTgUBaVLaOGQAG1uYyyRkALrXGaWrG2800cKRGi25BifbxLgIXiGlAwdAgBAtdLIfEIFFQDpzPoDIaxEZjG4JhZJlZrDZbZA7dJ7CCHAAUimarWojQr6TzN32AEpqOTFMAOJJo7GS-gvKdzpdqD2vEQGdyeV0oFB1oM4IMehRwxAOGMflD0aZlZFooC+BxkExkHBkEIRCYvGPB94tLQT8wxu6LLQaN67sPCCLL4ltFZ9IZWBvzCidwaRfM8iG5GVcCvXwaBiYJ-wfKJYOGEJQK8MRX0IRC1Q1cFfCHN8GTAf4UEpakUEUGAOTHdlt0UXccTgPEMWI2kKGQSio3Sfs-CZMcmUQlc1wxaFD2PRhoCZMDCAZedVkgPdoCnDwSKgCAxgYdB3jqF4jHeL4gUBH5pMxXltClYx0PEBs8CAA)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to narrow the type to a specific member of the union without using a literal type to discriminate but I'd love to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect more then ONE error in a generic

The error in `defaultOverwrite` will appear as soon as you fix the error in `configs`

```
checker({
    configs: {
        key1: { type: 'number', default: 1 }, // error fixed
        key2: { type: 'boolean', default: true },
        key3: { type: 'string', default: 'string' },
    },
    defaultOverwrite: {
        key1: '1' // a new error has spawned
            // (property) key1?: number | undefined
            //Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
    }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2yDeAoZQ5MATwAcIAuZAchCwCNoaAaAogEwnnQBsxq9TEyh4AvnjyhIsRCgBCAe0W9c7QqQrUaDZbwhwQNdci49+1XSoMhxk6dHhJkAZTBQ1RYuSq0Azu6gAOasJmZwfALIAVDBdniaKACqIMCKIAAqPsgAvGhYyAA+yEoqRa7u9uCOcsgAkgDyZGBpIAA8GcgQAB6QIBx+0YEgQSzIAMIAYgDiXb0Q-YMAShAIilAcHWMprVkUAHz7nkRrIDDAQX7UU9NsXgD09-Wm6TRgyADWIIoA7sgAFr9iIpkD9YpBiP9gINeKAUGAQZg4B8UAYEP9PhASMgkWB0RBBsAwINfiBkAA3OC8dDwnwmR7IYAAOggTOQAAMcCiSABGagYTBjbkAJmopV4QqxAGZqG4oGJ2WFuBF+A1ydAwUSIAB+agABTgUBaVLaOGQAG1uYyyRkALrXGaWrG2800cKRGi25BifbxLgIXiGlAwdAgBAtdLIfEIFFQDpzPoDIaxEZjG4JhZJlZrDZbZA7dJ7CCHAAUimarWojQr6TzN32AEpqOTFMAOJJo7GS-gvKdzpdqD2vEQGdyeV0oFB1oM4IMehRwxAOGMflD0aZlZFooC+BxkExkHBkEIRCYvGPB94tLQT8wxu6LMgpd67sPCCLL4ltFZ9IZWBvzCidwaRfM8iG5GVcCvXwaBiYJ-wfKJYOGEJQK8MRX0IRC1Q1cFfCHN8GTAf4UEpakUEUGAOTHdlt0UXccTgPEMWI2kKGQSio3Sfs-CZMcmUQlc1wxaFD2PRhoCZMDCAZedVkgPdoCnDwSKgCAxgYdB3jqF4jHeL4gUBH5pMxXltClYx0PEBs8CAA)